# select query laravel con fechas

Tags: laravel-5

Necesito impedir ingresar un nuevo evento si ya habia otro anterior con las fechas con hora esten en ese rango.
Para esto intente usar el tipico where con <=start y >=end pero no funciono y como ultimo intento use esto pero tampoco dio resultado.

```
$eventexist =DB::table('events')->where('doctor_id', $input['doctor_id'])->whereBetween('start', array($input['start'], $input['end']))->whereBetween('end', array($input['start'], $input['end']))->first();
```

Es decir cuando antes tengo una evento con inicio 01-01-2017 3:00 y termino 01-01-2017 4:00 si en la tabla eventos existe un registro inicio 01-01-2017 3:30 y termino 01-01-2017 3:45 no deberia insertarse.

Comment: Según el ejemplo que das (un poco confuso), ¿qué valores tendrían `$input['start']` e `$input['end']`?

Comment: tienen el siguiente formato 31-01-2017 01:00

Comment: Me refiero a los valores, no al formato.

Comment: primero obtengo con  $input = Input::all(); todos los input del form despues uso esto $input['start']=new Carbon($input['display-startdoctor']); y para el  $input['end'] uso  $sta=new Carbon($input['display-startdoctor']);      
        $endDate = $sta->addHour();
        $input['end']=$endDate;